# I am running putty.bat file. Inside bat file I am writing del command to remove unnnecessary files which part of putty needs to be deleted

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, putty, del

After running the batfile, putty is getting installed but  del command should remove the unnecessary files part of putty, it is not deleting.
my installing directory: `C:\Amaze\tool`

```
start msiexec.exe /i %~dp0putty-64bit-0.74-installer.msi > putty_log.txt 2>&1

del "%TARGETDIR%\putty-64bit-0.74-installer.msi.sha1"
```

The `del` command should remove the files of putty but it is not happening.

```
del "%TARGETDIR%\putty-64bit-0.74-installer.msi.sha1". Is there any issue with the del command and 
%TARGETDIR% is it going to path C:\Amaze\tool.
```

Installer should run after installer runs the files needs to be deleted. why I am unable to delete files, let me know what needs to be done so that I can remove the files.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this step and it is working:

```
start /wait /i %~dp07z1900-x64.exe > puttylog.txt 2>&1

del %~dp0putty*
```